# How to avoid NaN in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, nan

of course I know I should write better code which just not create NaN values.
But is there any casual method to avoid it. I mean something like:

```
if (!(floatNumber == NaN))
   // do some stupid function
else
return;
```

But it doesn't work for me. I also tried `floatNumber==null`, but also no result.
Could you please help me?

Comment: OK, Thanks for info, but could you provide any link to that duplicated thread, that I could read it and find the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test whether a number is NaN, you can use the standard library function [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan).

Comment: Thanks, but how to use it? Something like that? `if(floatNumber == std::isnan)` or some other way?

Comment: @pajczur You call it with a floating-point number to check if it's NaN. In other words, instead of `if (!(floatNumber == NaN))`, you'd write `if (!std::isnan(floatNumber))`

Comment: Then let those who come after apply floating point optimization option, and u have a bug. That is, this answer is advice to write brittle code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Since when is a documented standard library function "brittle code"?

Comment: @user4815162342: If you're referring to `std::isnan`, that's since C++11. It's not the standard's fault though. It's the implementations that fail to do this properly, and that's the reality that you need to relate to.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That sounds like an issue that should be reported to the compiler vendor. If my understanding is correct, it doesn't even happen with the default flags?

Comment: @user4815162342: Vendors plural. And you're right, the default behavior is that it works. That's why the code is *brittle*, not straight incorrect.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The code - or rather, the recommendation to use the standard library - is fine, it's the combination of buggy compiler and its non-standard switch that is _brittle_.